# Pandas groupby where one of the group values is in a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to find the sizes of the groups that have at least one row with `0.5 < C < 1.0`. Given a dataframe like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.9 |
| 1 | 2 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 5 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 4 | 0.6 |

I'd like to see something like the following returned:

| A | B | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |

I've tried the following:

```
group = dataset.groupby(['A', 'B'])
filtered = group.filter(lambda x: 0.5 < x['C'] < 1.0)
filtered.size()
```

However, I get this error on the second line:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

The `any()` function makes sense in this context as I want *any* value for `C` to be between 0.5 and 1.0 in order to count that group, but I don't know where to put the `any()` call. I tried calling it on the lambda. I tried after `filter()`. Nothing I try works...

Comment: @Kris won't that give me back only rows with `0.5 < C < 1.0`? I want _all_ the rows where their group as at least one row with `0.5 < C < 1.0`.

Comment: If your left-constraint was `<=` you could use [`.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html). So `df["C"].between(0.5, 1, inclusive=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `any` in the boolean indexing of the `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).size()[df.groupby(['A','B']).apply(lambda g:((g['C'] > 0.5) & (g['C'] < 1.0)).any())]
```

prints

```
A  B
1  2    3
3  4    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That's where I needed to put the `any()`!

Comment: :-) appreciate the vote and glad it helped figure out the any() issue! Some other solutions are, arguably, more elegant though

Answer (score 4):

```
df["tmp"] = (df["C"] > 0.5) & (df["C"] < 1.0)
g = df.groupby(["A", "B"])
print(g.size()[g["tmp"].sum() > 0])
```

Prints:

```
A  B
1  2    3
3  4    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just do `sum`

```
out = df.C.between(.5,1).groupby([df['A'],df['B']]).sum().loc[lambda x : x!=0]
Out[180]: 
A  B
1  2    2
3  4    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(
    {'C': lambda x: len(x) if np.logical_and(0.5 < x.values,  x.values < 1.).sum() else None}
).dropna().astype(int).rename(columns={'C': 'size'})

     size
A B      
1 2     3
3 4     1
```

Or if you prefer `A` and `B` as columns:

```py
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(
    {'C': lambda x: len(x) if np.logical_and(0.5 < x.values,  x.values < 1.).sum() else None}
).dropna().astype(int).rename(columns={'C': 'size'}).reset_index()

   A  B  size
0  1  2     3
1  3  4     1
```